# functional Option type in c# not support invariant

Tags: c#, option-type

A blueprint for interface like this:

```
   public interface IOption<out T>{
      IOption<R> Map<R> (Func<T, R> func);
      IOption<R> FlatMap<R> (Func<T, IOption<R>> func);
      T Get ();
      bool IsEmpty ();
      Y GetOrElse (Func<Y> defaultValue) where Y: T;//error
    }
```

The important point is it should support variant. I stuck on `Y GetOrElse (Func<Y> defaultValue) where Y: T;`.

error shows `The covariant type parameter T must be contravariantly valid on IOption<T>.GetOrElse(Func<T>)`.

Besides, Func should defined as `public delegate R Func<in A, out R>(A a);` .NET2.0 not append varient to `Func` generic type.

Thanks any advise.

**UPDATE**
From `Scala` language's Option design. I known `Y` should as `T`'s supertype but it seems can't define `where T: Y`simply, how should I do?

I also have another question - why can't define `T GetOrElse<T> (T defaultValue);`straightly???

Comment: Your interface is already covariant in the result type, so you could just define `T GetOrElse(Func<T> defaultValue)`.

Comment: @Lee, compiler print a error because `Func`'s T can't as convariant. it defined as `delegate T Func<out T>()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# does not support lower-bounds on generic parameters like scala, but you can make `GetOrElse` an extension method to make use of the covariance of the `IOption<T>` interface:

```
public static T GetOrElse<T>(this IOption<T> opt, Func<T> defaultValue)
{
    return opt.IsEmpty() ? defaultValue() : opt.Get();
}
```

then you can specify the type you want at the call site e.g.:

```
IOption<Dog> do = ...;
var ao = o.GetOrElse<Animal>(() => new Cat());
```

Comment: a new error occurred: `error CS1106: IOptionEx.GetOrElse<T>(this IOption<T>, Func<T>): Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class` .

Comment: sorry, I forgot `static` for extension class